# 'ajaxurl' is undefined -- wp-includes/js/wp-lists.js

Tags: javascript, errors

[My site](http://www.superlogical.net/) displays the following script error in IE8:

```
Webpage error details
Message: 'ajaxurl' is undefined
Line: 1
Char: 102
Code: 0
URI: http://www.superlogical.net/wp-includes/js/wp-lists.js?ver=20110521
```

I can't see what is calling wp-lists.js.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`wp-lists.js` seems to be one of scripts, used in WP admin. Assuming `ajaxurl` is defined is from there as well.

This is likely some plugin, trying to use these in admin area but (being poorly coded) loading them everyhwere.

Comment: Thanks.  The code ajaxurl is only contained in two plugins: Add This, and Wordpress SEO.  I will see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: :-S  Deactivating them one by one didn't make a difference - error is still there.

Comment: @Steve don't search for that, it might just be called in one of scripts internally. Look for something like `wp_enqueue_script('wp-lists')`.